# deployment assembly using maven-eclipse-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-eclipse-plugin

I am using maven-eclipse-plugin for working with a war project. This war project uses maven overlay method to include another war. When I deploy it using Maven, everything goes well. When I test the war locally in eclipse, it fails because the dependent war resources are available only in the target folder. To solve this, I go the deployment assembly and manually add the target folder. Is there way I could tell eclipse-maven-plugin to add the following line to org.eclipse.wst.common.component file inside the .settings folder when running the eclipse:eclipse goal.

```
<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/target/finalname"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can embed any additional eclipse properties in your pom for mvn eclipse:eclipse.

The [plugin reference](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html) has some examples for adding build commands, resources, facets, and of course also adhoc configuration.

You can probably copy paste something from there to help you.

Comment: I had gone over this, could not find a suitable way. additionalConfig is for new configuration files. org.eclipse.wst.common.component file has other details in it as well which is written by the plugin.